# Power BI - Create a transaction based table based on input

Tags: powerbi

I need to create "New Column" with the inputs I have in columns A, B and C. For every project and every Q there needs to be all periods.

How can I do this in Power BI? Or if not possible in Power BI, in Excel?

[image: 1]

The reason for this is to connect a different transaction table with missing periods and this "complete" period table will solve my problem. My calculated value is an accumulated value which in some months does not have value, therefore I need this table along with a formula in New Column D which will match the transactions table and choose the earlier number if nothing is found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DAX `CROSSJOIN` function to return the cartesian product of multiple tables in a new table:

```
OutputTable = 
VAR TblA = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS ( Table1[Column A], FILTER ( Table1, Table1[Column A] <> "" ) )
VAR TblB = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS ( Table1[Column B], FILTER ( Table1, Table1[Column B] <> "" ) )
VAR TblC = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS ( Table1[Column C] )
RETURN CROSSJOIN ( TblA, TblB, TblC )
```

See https://excel.solutions/so20181206_crossjointable/ for a worked example.

I think you may have more success if you actually converted your "Column C" values to dates, then used a Calendar table, and the Time Intelligence functions of DAX. It's hard to advise further without more understanding of your actual data structure and measure requirements.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I tried it, but i get an error that says : DAX-comparison operations does not support comparison of values integer and text. I thought this was because it recognized 2018Q1 (Column C) as text and edited the format to Int64.type and tried 20181 but i still get the same error. Also tried all the "null" values that are empty and set them to zero. This did not work either. If i would get the "new columns" described it would solve my issue. I have tried with only numbers with same formula so I suspect it's something with the formula. Thanks again! Hope you have a tip!

Comment: Is your data in Columns A, B and C exactly as in your screenshot? It sounds like you have a number value in A or B...

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot. The project number column automatically formatted column A to Integer when i used numbers with headers. When it was changed to type text and removed header as you, it worked